# Checking Spring Boot Application Health Without Actuator

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to write an application monitoring program that will monitor multiple applications running across multiple servers (many of them may be on the same server). I'm looking for a way to check whether each individual application is up or down, rather than the server as a whole, and possibly also get average response time. If the artifact version can also be retrieved, that would be a bonus.

Sadly, a lot of these applications are legacy, and not entirely configured properly, so the Spring Boot Health actuator isn't working on many of them, while others don't have Spring Boot at all.

What options are there for getting the status of these applications short of fixing all of them, or implementing new endpoints for them?

Edit: The list of applications that need monitoring is pretty large, so implementing something new for all of them would be less efficient than what I'm trying to accomplish.

Thanks!

Comment: Hit each individual service to check if they are up or not.

Comment: It’s not so hard to create similar functionality by yourself, the most effort is to implement checkers for your app dependencies, rest is rather simple. We did something similar by creating an interface for health indicator and registering it’s implementations as Spring beans, then those beans automatically infected into health manager bean to trigger a checking.

Comment: @Acewin Wouldn't that require building a list containing a safe endpoint for each service? Some of these applications don't have a GET endpoint.

Comment: @webdizz Right, but I was hoping for something a little more elegant that wouldnt require implementing something new for every application, since the list of apps to monitor is rather extensive.

Comment: You can publish metrics with DropWizard. It will not require Spring Boot actuator.